# React Native second line of text shifted left

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, styling, text-alignment

[image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gbgy.png)
As you can see in the screenshot, the text is not properly aligned on the left. The component looks like this:

```
<View style={s.title}>
   <Text style={s.titleText}> {article.title}</Text>
</View>
```

and the styling is:

```
    title: {
        width: "90%",
        backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    titleText: {
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "left",
    },
```

Here's what I tried so far:

- Add different paddings and margins
- Add the numberOfLines property and set it to 1/2/3
- Unwrap the  Component out of its partent  Component
- Tried some different settings with "alignItems" and "justifyContent" properties

Comment: check if your string in text tag has an empty space at the start, if it does have it and you cannot change the text just use article.title.trim() in you code to get rid of empty spaces

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-thompson-qyd8d6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Okay at this point this is just embarrassing. There's a space " " before the {article.title} in the Text Component. And I almost lost my mind. When will these mistakes ever stop happening? I'll just leave this here if someone is just as stupid as I am....